# How to /summon a tipped arrow?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to use `/summon` to summon an Instant Damage II Arrow, but I cannot figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The regular arrow entity will be considered a tipped arrow if it has the `Potion` string or `CustomPotionEffects` list present:

```
/summon Arrow ~ ~1 ~ {Potion:"minecraft:strong_harming"}
/summon Arrow ~ ~1 ~ {CustomPotionEffects:[{Id:7b,Duration:20,Amplifier:1b}]}
```

Comment: As always, you are my savior <3